# Serialize object to XML with xmlns attribute only, without prefix

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to serialize my Root object:

```
public class Root{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "docs", Namespace = "http://example.com/osoz-edi")]
    public Documents Documents{get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "docs")]
public class Documents {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "invoice", Namespace = "")]
    public Invoice Invoice{get;set;}
}
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "invoice", Namespace = "")]
public class Invoice {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", Namespace = "")]
    public string Id{get;set;}
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "number", Namespace = "")]
    public string Number{get;set;}
}
```

to XML like this:

```
<Root xmlns:ksx="http://example.com/osoz-edi">
    <docs xmlsns="http://example.com/osoz-edi">
        <invoice>
            <id>1</id>
            <number>222</number>
        </invoice>
    </docs>
</Root>
```

But I get something like this:

```
<Root xmlns:ksx="http://example.com/osoz-edi">
    <ksx:docs>
        <invoice>
            <id>1</id>
            <number>222</number>
        </invoice>
    </ksx:docs>
</Root>
```

I'm serializing using this:

```
var root = new Root(); 
.... //filling object with data
using (var sww = new StringWriter())
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
{   
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(); 
    ns.Add("ksx", "http://example.com/osoz-edi");   
    XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stylesheet));
    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, root, ns);   
}
```

When I serialize without passing XmlSerializerNamespaces, I get XML like this:

```
<Root>
    <docs xmlns="http://example.com/osoz-edi">
        <invoice>
            <id>1</id>
            <number>222</number>
        </invoice>
    </docs>
</Root>
```

How to do get namespace in root element, and attribute in docs element?

Comment: `xmlsns`? Is that a typo?

Comment: In your "to XML like this" sample, you don't actually use the `ksx` namespace anywhere?

Comment: The result you're trying to create (with an XML namespace of `ksx` which is completely unused) doesn't make sense, from an information standpoint.

Comment: From : XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Stylesheet));  To : XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

Comment: xmlsns - yes it's typo, should be xmlns

Answer (score 0):

Your Root class is missing an XmlRoot attribute:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Root", Namespace = "http://example.com/osoz-edi"]
public class Root
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, your other two classes do not need the XmlRoot attribute.

XmlElementAttribute says "This field or property represents a child element"; XmlRootAttribute says "This is a potential format for the root element of an XML document".